# Given a DAG X<-Z->Y, how to test for conditional independence of X and Y given Z for non-normal random variables?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, independence, conditional

Consider data generated from a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of the form X<-Z->Y.  Based on d-separation of DAGs, X is independent of Y given Z: X_||_Y|Z.  If X, Y and Z are multivariate normal, then the following three methods of testing for conditional independence give identical results:

1. test for a zero partial correlation r(X,Y|Z)
2. test for a zero partial slope for X in a linear regression lm(Y~Z+X)
3. test for a zero partial slope for Y in a linear regression lm(X~Z+Y)

However, when X, or Y are non-normal, and I fit a generalized linear model with a distributional family that is appropriate for X or Y, then the null probabilities of the following two glms do not give identical results even though X and Y are still conditionally independent given Z:
1b) test for a zero partial slope for X in a glm regression glm(Y~Z+X)
2b) test for a zero partial slope for Y in a glm regression glm(X~Z+Y)

Why does this happen?  If the null hypothesis of a zero partial slope is equivalent to the null hypothesis of conditional independence in these cases (?) then I would expect that the null probabilities associated with (1b) and (2b) would be the same.